# Remove Sidebar for Certain route React

Tags: reactjs

I want to remove the sidebar for one route on my react application. i didn't want that sidebar on my particular route called "Visual" any help from you guys would be much appreciated
my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./components/Home";
import SideBar from "./components/Sidebar";

import Apps from './components/login'
import Inference from './components/drop';
import New from './components/new'
import Visual from './components/visual'
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
             <Router>
        <div className="wrapper">
        <Route exact path="/visual" component={Visual} />
          <SideBar  />
          
           
            <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
          
          <Route exact path="/inference" component={Inference} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Apps} />
          <Route exact path="/new" component={New} />
          
 
        </div>
      </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be easier to implement if you have a `Layout` component with the sidebar in it. For example, the layout component would look like

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Sidebar />
      <main className="content">{children}</main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So routes that require the `Sidebar` can be wrapped with the `Layout` component. For example, your Home route would be

```
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        Home page content/JSX
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

This way, only routes using the `Layout` component would have the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your current path using `useLocation` hook that `react-router-dom` provides it. You can watch the routes that you are visiting and while you get to one that you don't want to show something return null instead of the component.

```js
const DummyComponent = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  if (pathname === '/somewhere') return null;
  return (
    <div>This is my component</div>
  );
}
```

I think this is going to work for you